# Colab notebook cannot find python module on mounted Google Drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

1. I successfully mounted google Drive in colab notebook
2. I have a module car1 in the folder of google drive /content/drive/MyDrive/python_scripts/car1.ipynb

I tried to run the following code in the colab cell

```
%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/python_scripts
from car1 import Car
from electric_car import ElectricCar

my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'roadster', 2019)
```

3. I get the error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-13-5762e8f9d6be> in <module> 2 3 ----> 4 from car1 import Car 5 from electric_car import ElectricCar 6

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'car1'
```

Comment: .ipynb files are not python modules, you cannot import them in python.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was indeed an error.

I now have the car1.py file with the path /content/drive/MyDrive/python_scripts/car1.py

But I still get the same error.


/content/drive/MyDrive/python_scripts
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-5762e8f9d6be> in <module>
      2 
      3 
----> 4 from car1 import Car
      5 from electric_car import ElectricCar
      6

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'car1'